# Can you play any amount of lands with future sight?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you play [Future sight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFuture%20sight%5d), you have already played a land during your turn, and you have a land on top of your library, can you play the land that is on top of your library without infringing the "one land per turn" rule?

Comment: You can with [Fastbond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382934) in play :) (there are also [lots of other cards that let you put one or more extra lands into play each turn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+%5Bplay%5D+%5Badditional%5D+%5Bland%5D))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No you can not**

This is covered in the Rulings on the Gatherer Page for [Future Sight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=413592).

> If the top card of your library is a land, you may play that land only if you have any available land plays.

Answer (score 9):

No.

[Future Sight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFuture%20Sight%5d) does not instruct you or give you permission to play a card. It merely extends the choice of cards that you can play when you are given permission to play cards. You must still be given permission to play the card, and any restrictions that apply must still be followed.

So, if it's a land, the following conditions must be met (by default):

- It must be your turn.
- It must be a main phase.
- The stack must be empty.
- You must have priority.
- You must not have played any land yet this turn.

This is confirmed by rulings on Future Sight:

> You must follow the normal timing permissions and restrictions for the top card of your library and pay its costs. [...]

> If the top card of your library is a land, you may play that land only if you have any available land plays.

---

> 305.1. A player who has priority may play a land card from his or her hand during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty. Playing a land is a special action; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule 115). Rather, the player simply puts the land onto the battlefield. Since the land doesn’t go on the stack, it is never a spell, and players can’t respond to it with instants or activated abilities.
>
> 305.2. A player can normally play one land during his or her turn; however, continuous effects may increase this number.
>
> 305.2a To determine whether a player can play a land, compare the number of lands the player can play this turn with the number of lands he or she has already played this turn (including lands played as special actions and lands played during the resolution of spells and abilities). If the number of lands the player can play is greater, the play is legal.